# SQL server: what does this sql statement mean

Tags: sql-server

I've been comparing databases using vs 2010 scheme comparing tool and it generated some stuff which is not clear. For example at the end of the script it has this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[My_table] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FOREIGN_ID];
```

Can anyone explain what this means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that existing data should be checked against the constraint when it is added.

Failure to have the `CHECK CHECK` leaves your constraints [untrusted](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1539/avoid-untrusted-constraints-in-sql-server/) and they cannot be used by the query optimiser.

Answer (score 1):

That tells SQL Server to validate the constraint against new rows. The counter example would be to use `WITH NOCHECK` to temporarily disable validation checks for new rows.

[ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL) (WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

Comment: The syntax is `[ WITH { CHECK | NOCHECK } ] { CHECK | NOCHECK } CONSTRAINT`. Your answer explains one half. Mine the other!

Comment: @MartinSmith - I suppose the only thing the BOL leaves out is explicitly mentioning that the constraints are untrusted. It does say it but in a verbose manner: *Any constraint violations that are suppressed by WITH NOCHECK when the constraint is added may cause future updates to fail if they update rows with data that does not comply with the constraint.* I.e., not trusted.